# TypeScript: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've a reusable component that accepts an optional onClick callback function as a prop.

I've defined the Props interface as folllows:

```
interface Props {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  optionalClickFn?: () => void;
}
```

The functional React (JSX) component as follows:

```
const ExampleComponent = (props: Props) => {
    return{
        { props.optionalClickFn ? <div
          className="delete-btn"
          onClick={() => props.optionalClickFn()}
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimesCircle} color="red" />
        </div> : <div></div>}
         }
}
```

I've defined an optional prop 'optionalClickFn', therefore I am first checking if it exist before executing the function. However, i still get the error: *Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.*

Comment: That's correct, it is possibly undefined per your prop definition. What *do* you want the component to do if that prop is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Making the check that way was not working. If I put another if condition inside the onClick prop, it works as expected.

```
  {props.optionalClickFn ? (
    <div
      className="delete-btn"
      onClick={() => {
        if (props.optionalClickFn) {
          return props.optionalClickFn();
        }
      }}
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimesCircle} color="red" />
    </div>
  ) : <div></div>}
```

I'm still unsure why it doesn't work the way I wrote in the original question though.